# Append html if no rows are visible with selected dropdowns

Tags: javascript, select, filter, html-table, append

I'm using this script([filtering html table columns with select dropdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66989506/filtering-html-table-columns-with-select-dropdowns)) from an old Question to filter a table via select options and I would like to append data, when all rows are hidden/ or when there are no results under that filter choise.

I basically want to add sth like, no results found under this query.

I've tried adding something like this, but nothing is happening.

```js
const
  table = document.querySelector('.filter-table'),
  filterState = {};

const dataFromRow = (row, headers) =>
  Object.fromEntries([...row.querySelectorAll('td')]
    .map((td, index) => [headers[index], td.textContent]));

const matchesCriteria = (rowData, filters) =>
  filters.every(([key, value]) => rowData[key] === value);

const refresh = () => {
  const
    headers = [...table.querySelectorAll('thead th')].map(th => th.textContent),
    filters = Object.entries(filterState),
    showAll = filters.length === 0;
  table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr').forEach(row => {
    const show = showAll || matchesCriteria(dataFromRow(row, headers), filters);
    row.classList.toggle('hidden-row', !show);
  });
};

const handleFilterChange = (e) => {
  const
    field = e.target.dataset.field,
    value = e.target.value;
  if (value) { filterState[field] = value; }
  else { delete filterState[field]; }
  refresh();
};

document.querySelectorAll('.filter').forEach(filter =>
  filter.addEventListener('change', handleFilterChange));

                        const jobrow = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr.hidden-row");
                        hiddenrows = Array.from(jobrow);
                        console.log(hiddenrows);
                        let result = hiddenrows.every(isSameAnswer);

                        function isSameAnswer(el, index, arr) {
                        if (index === 0) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return (el.answer === arr[index - 1].answer);
                        }
                        }
```

```css
  .filter-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  .filter-table {
    border: thin solid grey;
  }
  
  .filter-table thead {
    border-bottom: thin solid grey;
  }
  
  .filter-table th, .filter-table td {
    padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  }
  
  .filter-table th {
    background: #CCC;
  }
  
  .filter-table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #EEE;
  }
  
  .hidden-row {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
  <select class="filter" data-field="Status">
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="OK">OK</option>
  <option value="NO">NO</option>
</select>
<select class="filter" data-field="Cough">
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="No">No</option>
  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
<select class="filter" data-field="Fever">
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="No">No</option>
  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
<hr />
<table class="filter-table">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Status</th><th>Cough</th><th>Fever</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>OK</td><td>No</td><td>Yes</td></tr>
    <tr><td>NO</td><td>Yes</td><td>Yes</td></tr>
    <tr><td>OK</td><td>No</td><td>No</td></tr>
    <tr><td>NO</td><td>Yes</td><td>No</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: "I've tried adding something like this, but nothing is happening." Something like what? There is nothing in your example that shows what you have tried to do to display a message like that.

Comment: I've tried putting all tr.hidden-row into an array and couldn'T even do that.

The JS I used is in the code at the top.

Comment: Are you talking about this? `const jobrow = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr.hidden-row"); hiddenrows = Array.from(jobrow); console.log(hiddenrows);`? That only happens when you first load the page. At that point you don't have any hidden rows. Are you expecting that to magically change as your "change" event handler runs?

Comment: Thank you. Any idea what else I can try? Can you point me in a direction,?

Comment: Added an answer since I now understand what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start by putting your code that determines how many rows are hidden *inside* your event handler (`handleFilterChange`). Where you have it does nothing because that runs when the script loads, not when the event fires. From there, you should be able to use that to determine if any rows are showing and use that to display the extra message.

Specifically, you can put this inside handleFilterChange:

```
var hiddenRowCount = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr.hidden-row").length;
var totalRowCount = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr").length;

if (totalRowCount === hiddenRowCount) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much.  I got it to work. Only oddly sometimes when it loads it adds class .hidden-row to all rows even though nothing has been chosen yet.